# The sentence "The rodents are believed to have been got(ten) rid of by the end of the month"? is supposed to be correct. Why?

Tags: tense, passive-voice, future-perfect, future-constructions

> The rodents are believed to have been got(ten) rid of by the end of the month

My classmates told me that a teacher of mine claims that this sentence should be correct but I don't understand why as there is no future expressed even though there is the "by the end of the month" which, as far as I know, should indicate using future perfect construction. Is that because of the introducting "be believed to"? Can somebody please help?

Comment: "I was said that this sentence should be correct"    -  Who told you this.  Where did you see the sentence?

Comment: Also "I was told..." not "I was said ..."

Comment: Yeah, of course, "I was told", sorry, I wrote this in rush. A teacher of mine, allegedly (that's what my classmate told me).

Comment: It makes sense if you understand it as referring to a past month, not looking forward to the end of the current month. "We believe that they had got rid of all the rodents by the end of [that] month."

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I think as well...

Comment: Or, alternatively, "The rodents will have been got rid of by the end of the/this month", meaning that by the end of the month, the action of getting rid of them is going to be completed. Would that be possible?

Comment: No, because _have been_ indicates that the process is already over.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is at best, very badly phrased. As Kate observes it might make sense is a context like

> The rat elimination program began on June 1st of last year.  Twenty rats were caught in the first week and five in the second.  No rats were caught in the third or fourth week of June.  The rodents are believed to have been <s>gotten rid of</s> eliminated by the end of <s>the month</s> June.

However without this kind of context, "by the end of the month" would refer to the current month and so the sentence would be incorrect.

It would be better to use "eliminate" instead of "get rid of", and to change "the month" to an explicit name of the month, for clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, shouldn't it be: "The rodents are believed to have BEEN eliminated by the end of June"?

Comment: Yes,  that's right.

Comment: It would be clearer as "It is believed that the rodents had been eliminated by the end of the month."